# Align a banner to center

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with aligning a banner.
It must not be a background-image, it can be an object or embed and it must be 100% of page, but it must keep visible the center part of banner when the page width is reduced.

Comment: Hello, can you share some code with us please?

Comment: HTML: <div class="promo_top">

 <img src="img/top+banner.jpg" alt="" />

</div>

CSS:

.promo_top{
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 height:89px;
 text-align:center;
 overflow:hidden;
}


.promo_top img{
 display:inline-block;
 margin:0px auto;
}

But it does not work

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Your question is not clear : you said it has to be an object or embed, so we assume it's a flash banner. Then in your last comment, it's just an image... So what is it then ? Please post your code or a fiddle.

Comment: It will be an image too. For some pages it can be a flash. For testing i choose a simple image. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: In case it will be a flash i should not make it as a background i think, but if it is any solution...

Comment: http://ziarulnational.md/ look at the top banner. there is the problem when i make the page smaller the text disappear. there is a old code that doesn't work so i tried another.

Answer (score 1):

[**Working Fiddle for both examples**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/UPDpM/)

I don't see any reason why not to use a background image.
(and if you regret this restriction, then here is a Working fiddle above)

If you have to use an image, you can achieve this with a simple JQuery function look at the working fiddle above.

```
var img = $("#bannerWithScript > img"); //or any selector you want for targeting your image

img.css({
    "top": "calc(50% - " + (img.height() / 2) + "px)",
    "left": "calc(50% - " + (img.width() / 2) + "px)"
});
```

Comment: thank you very much. i just was thinking about a script like this.

Comment: if you're satisfied with the answer, you should accept it as correct & vote-up.

Answer (score 0):

Add `width:100%` to `.promo_top img`?

http://jsfiddle.net/3Ydph/

**Edit**

If you don't like resizing the image, the quick and easy way *would* be a background image that's quite wide:

```
.promo_top{ 
    float:left; 
     width:100%; height:300px; text-align:center; overflow:hidden; 
    background-image:url(http://www.quoteserv.com/funny/images/bowie.gif);
    background-position:top center; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

The edges would then disappear to the left and right if the screen is too small for the banner, but stay centralised. New jsfiddle (just imagine the pic is very wide to match most screens)

http://jsfiddle.net/3Ydph/1/

Comment: Tried, it compress the image and look not so nice. Thank you any way. :)

Comment: ah, so you want the left & right to disappear out the sides?

Comment: yes, the main content will be in the middle

Comment: yes it is the way i'll prefer, but when on other pages it will be a flash banner it will not work.

Comment: Having the edges of a flash banner disappear off the sides of the page doesn't sound like a great idea; might users need to interact with the corners that can't be seen?

Comment: @Valentina Darii An alternative option might be to have a small-ish fixed-size image and have a matching background colour, but this relies on the flash banner / img being a solid colour on the edges. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3Ydph/2/ >> the .promo_top div's background colour makes it look like the image filles the page

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
.width_100 {width: 100%;}
.center {margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;}
```

**XHTML**

```
<div class="width_100">
 <img alt="Alternative Text" class="center" src="lulz.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work, thank you very much anyway.